# RAILS 4: Why blank view template needed for a custom PATCH action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In routes.rb, a custom route `/db_handler` is declared for `doper` in controller `user_menus` (NO model of `user_menu`):

```
  patch '/db_handler', :to => "user_menus#doper"

  root :to => "user_menus#home"
```

Here is `home.html.erb`.

```
<%= form_tag('/db_handler', :method => "patch") do %>
       .......
      <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end  %>
```

After clicking `submit`, there is an error:

```
Missing template user_menus/doper
```

After creating a blank `doper.html.erb`, the error disappears. I don't quite understand why Rails needs to have a blank `doper.html.erb` for a custom `patch` action. What's the reasoning for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect to other action once you done with your update, you wont be requiring a blank html template. If you do

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
end
```

Then it will require a blank template of it. It just means if you think to stay on your doper action, it will require a template, else if you redirect or ajaxify it. It will not require html template. Hence you can do:

```
redirect_to any_path_here
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your `UserMenusController#doper` method it's hard to say for sure, but I guess your `UserMenusController` is trying to perform its default behaviour for a request, which is to render a view. If no view is found, it throws this error because it doesn't know any better.

If you override the `doper` method for that controller so that it doesn't render a view, for example by adding `render nothing: true` at the end of the method, you wouldn't need this blank file any more.

Comment: There is no `render` or `redirect_to` in action `doper`

Comment: @user938363 right but that's the default action - if you don't specify something else it will always try to render the view. Check out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) for more info. If you put `render nothing: true` at the end of your `doper` action it will prevent this from happening.